# Export address book to vcard file

Tags: ios, ios5, vcf-vcard

I want to export Address book from iPhoneSDK to vcard file using base64decode.
I don't know how iPhoneSDK save file and How to export Contact to Vcard file?
Import is easy for me.
Somebody can help me with my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using iOS 5 or later there's a function in ABPerson that can return the vCard representation of the given person records:

```
 CFDataRef ABPersonCreateVCardRepresentationWithPeople(CFArrayRef people);
```

**Update:** If you need sample code for generating vCard that uses base64 click [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1645335/stock/iphone/vCard/altosh.zip)